# Arch Linux Graphics and Don't

Tags: display, fonts, arch-linux, fontconfig

I just installed Arch Linux with lightdm and awesome, and the fonts and display look very pixelated. I installed infinality, but it didn't seem to make much of a difference. I'm wondering if you all could send me a noob's introduction to configuring subpixel rendering and all that fancy stuff.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pixelated issue seems to me that you don't have the right screen resolution.
Try to read more about  [awesome window manager](http://awesome.naquadah.org/).